# Flask with PyMySQL error, fails at first request but all following requests succeed

Tags: flask, pymysql

I got an API by Flask and PyMySQL, the client is implemented via Axios in VUE. The very first request after opening the page **always** fails, but all the following requests will succeed. Mysteriously, if I insert a `breakpoint()`, the first request **will succeed** after step-by-step debug. These requests are totally the same. The error message by Flask and PyMySQL says that `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'`.

Here's the code of the API:

```py
@app.route(f"{api_url_prefix}/warning/details", methods=["GET"])
@siwa.doc(query=WarningDetailModel)
def warnings():
    args = request.args.to_dict(flat=True)
    if "startts" not in args or "endts" not in args:
        return "Error query, start and end timestamp must be fed"
    start = int(args.get("startts"))
    end = int(args.get("endts"))
    start_str = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(start).strftime(config.time_format)
    end_str = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(end).strftime(config.time_format)
    query_sql = "SELECT * FROM warning_data WHERE time > %(start_str)s AND time < %(end_str)s ORDER BY time DESC"
    query_dic = {
        "start_str": start_str,
        "end_str": end_str,
    }
    check_db_connection(conn)
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(query_sql, query_dic)
        res = cursor.fetchall()
        total_count = len(res)
    if res:
        # Correct the datetime format
        processed_res = []
        for item in res:
            item["time"] = item.get("time").strftime(config.time_format)
            processed_res.append(item)
        result = {
            "data": processed_res,
            "total_count": total_count,
        }
        return result
    else:
        return {
            "data": [],
            "total_count": 0,
        }
```

The tracebacks show that the error happens at the `cursor.execute()` statement. What's the error exactly?

FULL tracebacks:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/houlu/.local/share/virtualenvs/MQTT_client-e0BPhhQw/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/houlu/.local/share/virtualenvs/MQTT_client-e0BPhhQw/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/houlu/.local/share/virtualenvs/MQTT_client-e0BPhhQw/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 176, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/home/houlu/.local/share/virtualenvs/MQTT_client-e0BPhhQw/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/houlu/.local/share/virtualenvs/MQTT_client-e0BPhhQw/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/home/houlu/.local/share/virtualenvs/MQTT_client-e0BPhhQw/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_siwadoc/__init__.py", line 164, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "web.py", line 268, in warnings
    cursor.execute(query_sql, query_dic)
  File "/home/houlu/.local/share/virtualenvs/MQTT_client-e0BPhhQw/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 153, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/home/houlu/.local/share/virtualenvs/MQTT_client-e0BPhhQw/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 322, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/home/houlu/.local/share/virtualenvs/MQTT_client-e0BPhhQw/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 558, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/home/houlu/.local/share/virtualenvs/MQTT_client-e0BPhhQw/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 822, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/home/houlu/.local/share/virtualenvs/MQTT_client-e0BPhhQw/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1207, in read
    self._read_result_packet(first_packet)
  File "/home/houlu/.local/share/virtualenvs/MQTT_client-e0BPhhQw/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1283, in _read_result_packet
    self._get_descriptions()
  File "/home/houlu/.local/share/virtualenvs/MQTT_client-e0BPhhQw/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1368, in _get_descriptions
    field = self.connection._read_packet(FieldDescriptorPacket)
  File "/home/houlu/.local/share/virtualenvs/MQTT_client-e0BPhhQw/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 758, in _read_packet
    recv_data = self._read_bytes(bytes_to_read)
  File "/home/houlu/.local/share/virtualenvs/MQTT_client-e0BPhhQw/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 779, in _read_bytes
    data = self._rfile.read(num_bytes)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: @ewokx The full traceback is attached, thanks.

Comment: Which version of PyMySQL are you using?

Comment: Noticed this Issue https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/1013

Comment: @ewokx I use the latest version v1.1.0. The most weird thing is that the error occurs exactly right at the first request from webpage. Second, third... request works fine. Request by Postman works fine.